# Error on update-database Can't resolve Type for member

Tags: c#, json, entity-framework-migrations

When I try to press update-database on my Package Manager Console
I get this error

> Type is not resolved for member 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException,Newtonsoft.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=30ad4fe6b2a6aeed'.

How can I fix this error? My code is:

```
protected override void Seed(Gamer.DataLayer.GamerContext context)
        {
            // TODO:
            // Create a class GamerData to store a list of Games 
            // Deserialize the JSON string to a GamerData object (call this object gdata)

        var gdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GamerContext>(_json);
            Console.WriteLine(gdata.Games.Where(x => x.Language == "EN"));

            
            foreach (var game in gdata.Games)
            {

                foreach (var gameGenre in game.GameGenres)
                {
                    Genre myGenre = context.Genres.Where(g => g.GenreId == gameGenre.GenreId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (myGenre != null)
                        gameGenre.GenreId = myGenre.GenreId;
                }
                foreach (var platformGame in game.PlatformGames)
                {
                    Platform myPlatform = context.Platforms.Where(p => p.PlatformId == platformGame.Platform.PlatformId).FirstOrDefault();
                    if (myPlatform != null)
                        platformGame.Platform = myPlatform;
                }
                context.Games.Add(game);
                context.SaveChanges();

                // Add the data to your database           
            }
        }
```

**_json** Json is a string full of JSON which contains all my data of my database

**JSON String**

```
private string _json = @"{""Games"":[
{
    ""EAN"":""2750026762618"",
    ""GameName"":""Uncharted 4"",
    ""Language"":""en|nl"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""2750026762618"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""1"",
                ""GenreName"":""Actie""}
        },
        {             
            ""GameId"": ""2750026762618"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""2"",
                ""GenreName"":""Avontuur""}
        },
        {             
            ""GameId"": ""2750026762618"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""9"",
                ""GenreName"":""Role Playing Game""}
        },
        { 
            
            ""GameId"": ""2750026762618"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""10"",
                ""GenreName"":""Shooter""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""2750026762618"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""59.99""
        }   
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5030944112878"",
    ""GameName"":""Fifa 16"",
    ""Language"":""en"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5030944112878"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""1"",
                ""GenreName"":""Actie""}
        },
        {             
            ""GameId"": ""5030944112878"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""12"",
                ""GenreName"":""Sport""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030944112878"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""1"",
                ""PlatformName"":""PC""},                            
            ""Price"":""34.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030944112878"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""39.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030944112878"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""3"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Xbox One""},                            
            ""Price"":""39.99""
        } 
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5030948112294"",
    ""GameName"":""De Sims 4"",
    ""Language"":""nl"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5030948112294"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""11"",
                ""GenreName"":""Simulatie""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030948112294"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""1"",
                ""PlatformName"":""PC""},                            
            ""Price"":""71.08""
        }
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5030949112576"",
    ""GameName"":""Star Wars Battlefront"",
    ""Language"":""en"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5030949112576"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""2"",
                ""GenreName"":""Avontuur""}
        },
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5030949112576"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""10"",
                ""GenreName"":""Shooter""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030949112576"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""1"",
                ""PlatformName"":""PC""},                            
            ""Price"":""24.99""
        },  
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030949112576"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""24.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5030949112576"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""3"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Xbox One""},                            
            ""Price"":""34.99""
        }     
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5055856403357"",
    ""GameName"":""Doom"",
    ""Language"":""en"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856403357"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""1"",
                ""GenreName"":""Actie""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856403357"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""1"",
                ""PlatformName"":""PC""},                            
            ""Price"":""49.99""
        },  
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856403357"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""59.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856403357"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""3"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Xbox One""},                            
            ""Price"":""59.99""
        }     
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5060146463188"",
    ""GameName"":""Minecraft Story Mode"",
    ""Language"":""nl"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5060146463188"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""2"",
                ""GenreName"":""Avontuur""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5060146463188"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""30.99""
        },  
        {
            ""GameId"":""5060146463188"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""3"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Xbox One""},                            
            ""Price"":""31.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5060146463188"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""4"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Wii U""},                            
            ""Price"":""39.99""
        }     
    ]
},
{
    ""EAN"":""5055856406136"",
    ""GameName"":""Fallout 4"",
    ""Language"":""en"",
    ""GameGenres"":
    [
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856406136"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""1"",
                ""GenreName"":""Actie""}
        },
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856406136"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""2"",
                ""GenreName"":""Avontuur""}
        },
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856406136"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""5"",
                ""GenreName"":""Open wereld""}
        },
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856406136"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""9"",
                ""GenreName"":""Role Playing Game""}
        },
        { 
            ""GameId"": ""5055856406136"",
            ""Genre"":{
                ""GenreId"":""10"",
                ""GenreName"":""Shooter""}
        }
    ],
    ""PlatformGames"":
    [
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856406136"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""1"",
                ""PlatformName"":""PC""},                            
            ""Price"":""114.4""
        },  
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856406136"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""2"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Playstation 4""},                            
            ""Price"":""264.99""
        },
        {
            ""GameId"":""5055856406136"",
            ""Platform"":{
                ""PlatformId"":""3"",
                ""PlatformName"":""Xbox One""},                            
            ""Price"":""114.99""
        }     
    ]
}
]
}";
```

Anyone any idea what I am doing wrong?

**GamerContext**

```
using Gamer.DomainClasses.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace Gamer.DataLayer
    {
        public class GamerContext : DbContext
        {
            public GamerContext() : base("Gamer")
            { }
            public DbSet<Game> Games { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Genre> Genres { get; set; }
            public DbSet<PlatformGames> PlatformGames { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Platform> Platforms { get; set; }
            public DbSet<GameGenres> GameGenres { get; set; }
    
        }
    }
```

Comment: Obviously your json can not be deserialized to object GamerContext. Check _json string to make sure it's ok.
Looks like Context is something like DatabaseContext or else and you can not create Context object from simple string.

Comment: @inser 
Added my json string

Comment: I think you need to create new business class that will contains all this properties (what your json have) and use it. Context is much more complex object that is not serializable.

Comment: Or use dynamics :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON may have some properties that are different (different name, type, etc...) on your class.

TIP: If you want to debug `Seed` you need to launch the debugger by code:

```
protected override void Seed(dbEmployeePortal context)
{
    try
    {
        if(!Debugger.IsAttached)
            Debugger.Launch()
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    { // breakpoint here. This breakpoint needs to be set on the new visual studio that will open for the debug session.

    }
}
```

Comment: Just add that code at the start of my seed methode?

Comment: Trows me out when i want to reach get function of my gamerContext 


 will put in the question now

Comment: Try to put a try catch around all the seed method. Then on the catch place a breakpoint.